# PHP: Class 'Phar' not found

Tags: php, phar

I try to use the Silex framework as base for my web application. However, if I try to include the *.phar archive, PHP throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /var/www/framework/silex.phar on line 11
```

The following relevant lines are in my `/etc/php/php.ini` (as suggested in the docs of Silex):

```
extension=phar.so
phar.readonly = Off
phar.require_hash = Off
detect_unicode = Off
```

The PHAR library is present in `/usr/lib/php/modules/phar.so` which is set as the extension path for all libraries in my `php.ini`

Does anyone know why PHP is throwing this error?

Comment: Why do you need `detect_unicode` to be off?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try specifying the [path to the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698350/749181):

```
php -d extension=phar.so composer.phar <your_script>
```

**Other options:**

Based on the information you provided, there are a few possibilities:

- You are using a different php.ini. Check the output of `phpinfo()` to confirm, and ensure that you are editing the active one.
- /usr/lib/php/modules/phar.so is not readable. Ensure that the web server user can read this file.
- Your web server has not been restarted since you last added the phar-related information to php.ini. Restart your webserver.

Comment: Thanks, I checked all your suggestions. Unfortunately, the error remains the same.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer as you provide a good list what could be the cause. In my case, the webserver was configured in a way that it silently failed when reading the php.ini. So I didn't detect an error some lines above the `extension=phar.so` line.

Comment: I've never heard of PHP failing silently when it tried to read php.ini. Can you elaborate on the cause and solution?

Comment: Yeah, that was new to me, too. If I tried to launch a PHP script from the console (e.g. `php myscript.php`) an error returned that there was a another `.so` file missing. After commenting out this line, PHP could successfully run my script (in CLI and browser).

Answer (score 19):

This works for me:

```
php -d extension=phar.so composer.phar [... your command ...]
```

This includes the phar extension for the current runtime. Works for shared / VPC servers.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS ...

- `phar.so` is contained in the `php-common` package.
- the `phar` executable is contained in the `php-cli` package.
- `php-mbstring` and `php-bz2` also seems to be required.

When `php -m | grep phar` returns nothing, one has to add these `.ini` files for the CLI:

```sh
sudo cp /etc/php-zts.d/phar.ini /etc/php-cli.d/phar.ini
sudo cp /etc/php-zts.d/mbstring.ini /etc/php-cli.d/mbstring.ini
sudo cp /etc/php-zts.d/bz2.ini /etc/php-cli.d/bz2.ini
```

Alternatively, one can add the same module `.ini` files as the webserver uses:

```sh
sudo cp /etc/php-zts.d/* /etc/php-cli.d/
```

It should look alike this:

```sh
$ php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php-cli.d/
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php-cli.d/bz2.ini,
/etc/php-cli.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php-cli.d/phar.ini
```

Then one can run it:

```sh
$ php ./composer.phar
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
```

And move it below the `$PATH`:

```sh
sudo mv ./composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by install phar:

```
apt-get install php-phar
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I think you need `require_once 'phar://silex/silex.phar/autoload.php';` instead of `require_once 'silex/silex.phar';`. If this is not the case then we need to see the code throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

in my hosting environment i needed to specify the php version number. EG:

php-5.6 composer.phar

not

php composer.phar

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may shed some light. I was using a shared host and had trouble getting composer to run. I was using this sites directions http://avantidevelopment.com/install-composer-on-bluehost/ to setup a common directory and install composer in it. I followed it but shoud add for my alias I added the following command to .bashrc

```
alias composer='/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli ~/common/composer.phar'
```

That did the trick for me. Hope whoever stumbles on this sets off a light bulb.

Answer (score 0):

For Mageia 4, Mageia 5, Mageia 6 users

```
>> urpmi php-phar;echo done
To satisfy dependencies, the following packages are going to be installed:
  Package                        Version      Release       Arch
(medium "Core Release2")
  php-bz2                        5.6.30       2.mga6        x86_64
  php-phar                       5.6.30       2.mga6        x86_64
326KB of additional disk space will be used.
151KB of packages will be retrieved.
Proceed with the installation of the 2 packages? (Y/n) y


    $MIRRORLIST: media/core/release/php-bz2-5.6.30-2.mga6.x86_64.rpm
    $MIRRORLIST: media/core/release/php-phar-5.6.30-2.mga6.x86_64.rpm
installing php-phar-5.6.30-2.mga6.x86_64.rpm php-bz2-5.6.30-2.mga6.x86_64.rpm 
Preparing...                     ###############################################
      1/2: php-bz2               ###############################################
      2/2: php-phar              ###############################################
>>
```