# Problems with installing Symfony 2?

Tags: php, macos, symfony, composer-php

I installed Composer successfully and now I'm trying to install Symfony 2 on a Macbook 10.5.8.

I downloaded Symfony Standard 2.5.0 (.tgz) on http://symfony.com/download and I tried to use the `create-project` command to generate a new Symfony application using

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/to/install
```

but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /Users/jenisawesome/composer.phar on line 13
```

Maybe it's because I have an old php version? I'm not sure. I can't even run Composer when I type in this command:

```
php composer.phar
```

I get the same error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /Users/jenisawesome/composer.phar on line 13
```

Comment: What is your version of PHP? You need at least 5.3 I believe. Run `php -v`

Comment: Also, did you look search for that error and try anything else? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851099

Comment: my PHP version is 5.2.15, so ya. I guess I don't meet the requirements :\ Does that mean I have to download Symfony 1?

Comment: I would not recommend using Symfony 1. Why are you on such an old version? 5.2 and even 5.3 are very old and not recommended to use anymore. You should try and use 5.4 or 5.5 if possible.

Comment: My mac just came with the 5.2 version. I'm trying to update it to 5.3 or higher. I should really get a new computer :\

Comment: Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: I use mamp 1.9, but I don't really know how it works. I thought it was supposed to upgrade my php to at least 5.3 but it still stayed the same :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments, this error appears to be because you're using PHP 5.2. Composer [required at least 5.3.2](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements) to run.

Aside from that, this question appears to be a duplicate of [PHP: Class 'Phar' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851099/php-class-phar-not-found)